# How to call method from deep nested child component

Tags: reactjs

I have parent component with child, which have another child, and so on.

```
Parent
 | Child A
   | Child B
     | Child C
       ...
       | Child G
```

How can I call method in `Child G` from `Parent` without passing props for this? Can I use `Ref` for this?

Comment: You can use Context or Redux. In this simple example I suggest to use Context https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to pass props, you can use React's [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

I made a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/w7z905nzx8) for you.
Hope this helps, if you need more explanation, just let me know!

Comment: Unfortunately this link no longer works. Any chance the code could be pasted inside your answer?

Comment: @user4779 I just updated the link with the correct one. Apparently the code sandbox changed the url for some reason